# Clear TableHeader with ImageView turning white while scrolling [Swift]

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uitableview, uikit

Small question when I scroll the tableView, the background color of the header changes to white. I thinks it's a problem with _UIVisualEffectBackdropView, but I didn't know how to resolve that

[Without scrolling tableView](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eh7GP.png)

[When I scroll the tableView](https://i.stack.imgur.com/19cVr.png)

Comment: Show the code inside your TableHeader, or at least anything. I think it is a reuse problem, but can't tell you much unless I see any code.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.